# Necessary condition Riemann integrability ensures Lebesgue integrability

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Let f be bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. Illustrate an example that if f is Riemann integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, then it need not be Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. Determine a necessary condition under which Riemann integrability of f on $\mathbb{R}$ ensures the Lebesgue integrability.

I am following the book Measure Theory and Integration by G. de Barra and in the book, it has been discussed the equality of Riemann and Lebesgue integration over a finite interval. Can someone explain the relation between the two over the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There is no such thing as a Riemann integral over $\mathbb{R}$. The Riemann integral applies to bounded functions on finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.   Perhaps you mean the improper (Riemann) integral.  In that case $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx$ is a conditionally convergent improper integral, but $x \mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not Lebesgue integrable.  In fact, $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin x|}{x} \, dx = +\infty$, i.e. divergent.  If the improper integral is absolutely convergent, then it is equivalent to the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Oh okay I understand it now. Thank you!